# Is there a way to widen the scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, webkit

To preface, I am very new to coding altogether! It's simply a side hobby that I am learning to do alone. 
I'm intending to use an image as a scrollbar, but I want the image to be larger than the scrollbar width allows for. Is it feasible to do so?

```css
.scroll {
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
text-align: center;
overflow: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
color:#542323;
}

.scroll {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background: none;
}

.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: url('https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=16zywqQCwQ_ouIn-zBScMb-z50_k91oDq') no-repeat;
  background-size: 50%;
}

/* to add scrollability - added by Editor */
body {
  min-height: 1000vh;
}
```

This works alright, but the image is very tiny and increasing the background size ends up with the photo being cut off.

Comment: Simply use the `width` property...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webkit Scrollbar Width Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486965/webkit-scrollbar-width-change)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to write css for that. Preferable at the top of CSS file.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
}
```

You can add as much as you want. If you want to change colour then,

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: grey;
}
```